# Get the Class name in a class with atribute inside a attribute method

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm doing a Custom Authorize Attribute.

Want use this Attribute in class and controller level.

This code work on a Method level

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute([CallerMemberName] string callerName = null)
    {
        CallerName = callerName;
    }

    public string CallerName { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            return true;

        ...
        if (CallerName == something)
        {
            do this
        }
        ...

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

like that

```
    [CustomAuthorize()]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

But i want use globally in a controller

```
[CustomAuthorize()]
public class UsuariosController : Controller
{
    SalusDbContext db = new SalusDbContext();


    // GET: Usuarios
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Sorry the bad English.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i didn't need Reflection or anything fancy, in the AuthorizeAttribute i have the httpContext, with this i can get the Route, Controller and Action Name.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var routeValues = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;

        if (httpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            return true;

        var controller = routeValues["Controller"];
        var action = routeValues["Action"];

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```